# Send email to external address using SPD2013 workflow

Tags: 2013, designer-workflow, office-365, sharepoint-designer

I am trying to determine whether it *is* actually possible to send a SPD designer 2013 workflow to an external email address where SharePoint Online is being used.

I have seen various fora posts and blogs that collectively suggest that it either is/isn't/might be possible depending on the author's knowledge and experience and version of SP being used and others that say that by creating a Mail Contact or Mail User in the Exchange Online Admin Center will/may then expose the contact to the SPD2013 workflow in around 3 days (or when the moon aligns with Saturn or somesuch).

For future-proofing my workflow a little, I'm a little reluctant to use a SP2010 workflow and understand the 'security' reasons for SPD2013 workflows not immediately accepting external email addresses, but surely there is a wide enough need for this feature to be supported.

Has anyone been able to find a solution to this scenario?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a SharePoint Designer 2010 worflow. Check the second half of this post where he explains how to reuse the SharePoint 2010 workflow in SharePoint 2013 workflows.

[Send emails via WF post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/rajbugga/archive/2013/10/15/sharepoint-2013-unable-to-send-emails-to-external-email-addresses-sharepoint-2013-workflows.aspx)

If you have issues make sure its not an exchange isue. I found this thread helpful. [Thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/4a1849e8-e013-428a-95ba-fddec1e21422/sharepoint-designer-send-external-email)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible but with help 3rd party solutions. One of it is [Plumsail Workflow Actions Pack](http://plumsail.com/workflow-actions-pack/) that is contains [Send an Email with attachments](http://plumsail.com/workflow-actions-pack/docs/email-processing/#SmtpSendEmail) that support sending email to external users.

P.S.: I'm recommend this solution because I'm member of developer team, and I know it is good product.

Comment: That component is @ $500/year subscription.  Very nice, though; I wish I had it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use SP 2013 workflow functionality, but also send an email to external users then you should:

1. Create a SP2010 Workflow that handles just sending the email
2. Publish the SP2010 workflow
3. Create a SP2013 workflow, do all work here, except email
4. At point the SP2013 workflow should email out, instead have it run the SP2010 workflow, and pass in any relevant parameters.

Comment: Please don't add the exact same answer to this question, as you did on [this one](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/156840/6382). Instead, try to specify your answer further to make it a better of this specific question. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Smtp service needs domain alias for exact mail domains sharepoint sends. All other mail domains needs smart host config in props from relevant virt. smtp server in iis 6.0