# Workflow send e-mail to the external e-mail address

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I get new problem for me. I need to send an e-mail to the external e-mail address using workflow.

I have SharePoint Online(Office 365).
I found the information that `"SendEmail"` method works for this version with internal e-mail only. And the question is there any way to activate some hosted-app or java script which will send this e-mail using workflow?

Comment: Take a look at this http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/101744/how-do-you-send-emails-to-external-email-address-in-sharepoint-online-workflows Solution is to use 2010 workflow and call it from 2013 workflow

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the SharePoint Online Limitation, but their are couple of workaround for it.

1. As Amal mentioned, use the 2010 workflow.
2. add the [users as contact in Exchange](http://www.stefanfeenstra.nl/office-365/unable-send-emails-external-users-sharepoint-online-2013-experience/). This has the following disadvantage, it takes +/- 3 days to show up in SharePoint. Once User in the contact list then you can send the email to that address.[image]
3. To send email to external address, you need to invite the external address as the external user.http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/158/t/163866.aspx