# SHarePoint 2013 designer workflow not sending emails to read only initiator

Tags: sharepoint-server, designer-workflow

HI I have custom list created in one of our anonymous SharePoint 2013 site. List form can be filled by anyone from out side.I have a field called "Customer email" which i have to send initial email as well after approval/rejection email.
I have created a designer workflow in which I have set up "App step" as below
[image] but it is giving me error and the workflow doesn't start

here is the error "RequestorId: 6ba8ff34-935f-e361-0000-000000000000. Details: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow instance. Exception details: System.ApplicationException: HTTP 400 {"error":{"code":"-2130242040, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The e-mail message cannot be sent. Make sure the e-mail has a valid recipient."}}} {"Transfer-Encoding":["chunked"],"X-SharePointHealthScore":["0"],"X-SP-SERVERSTATE":["ReadOnly=0"],"DATASERVICEVERSION":["3.0"],"SPClientServiceRequestDuration":["221"],"SPRequestGuid":["6ba8ff34-935f-e361-a71d-fb0c0e9b676d"],"request-id":["6ba8ff34-935f-e361-a71d-fb0c0e9b676d"],"X-FRAME-OPTIONS":["SAMEORIGIN"],"MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices":["16.0.0.4900"],"X-Content-Type-Options":["nosniff"],"X-MS-InvokeApp":["1; RequireReadOnly"],"Cache-Control":["max-age=0, private"],"Date":["Wed, 25 Mar 2020 04:40:32 GMT"],"Server":["Microsoft-IIS/8.5"],"X-AspNet-Version":["4.0.30319"],"X-Powered-By":["ASP.NET"]}at Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine.SubroutineChild.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation) "

Can someone help me out on how to send email to external emails in SharePoint designer 2013 approval workflow.

Answer (score 0):

It's by default that SharePoint 2013 workflow is in only sending to users known by the tenant.

As a workaround, you could use SharePoint 2010 workflow platform impersonation step.

Here is a similar post for your reference: [How do you send emails to external email address in sharepoint online workflows](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/101744/how-do-you-send-emails-to-external-email-address-in-sharepoint-online-workflows)